# Printing a hollow triangle in alphabetical order anti-clock-wise

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently having some difficulty with this python pattern problem, where I am not able to generate the proper output, required to this problem. If I could receive some help or feedback from you guys that'll be great! Thank you!!

```
def print_triangle(sentence):
    if len(sentence) % 4 != 0:
        return False
    else:
        char_list = list(sentence)
        x = 0
        n = int(len(sentence) / 4) + 1
        for row in range(1,n+1):
            for col in range(1,2*n):
                if row ==n or row+col == n+1 or col-row == n-1:       
                    print(char_list[x] ,end="")
                    x += 1
                else:
                    print(end=" ")
            print()
        return True
```

if function `print_triangle('abcdefghijkl')` is called, it should be able to generate the following output:

```
   a
  b l
 c   k
defghij 
Return value:True
```

However, this is the output that I'm getting

```
    a    
   b c   
  d   e  
 fghijkl
 Return value:True
```

Comment: This is BTW not a pyramid but a triangle.

Answer (score 2):

Algorythm:

- row 0:  print spaces + first letter
- row 1:  print 1 less spaces + next letter, print row*2-1 spaces, print last letter
- row 2:  - the same, just print the letter before the last letter
- ...
- last row: print remaining letters up to (not including) those that being printed already:

---

```
def print_triangle(sentence):
    n = len(sentence)
    if n % 4 != 0:
        return False

    # special case handling ;)
    elif n==4:
        print(" " + sentence[0], sentence[1:], sep="\n")
        return True    
    else:
        numRows = n//4
        for row in range(numRows+1):    # amount of total triangle rows
            # end case, print the rest thats not been printed
            if row == numRows:
                print(sentence[row:-row+1])
                return True

            # normal case: print enough spaces, then 1 letter, do not end the line
            print(' '*(numRows - row)+sentence[row],end="")

            # on all but the first line: print padding spaces and last letter
            if row != 0:
                print(' '*(2*row-1)+sentence[n-row]) 
            else: 
                print("") # newline to "close" this line if on line 0
print("")
r = print_triangle(input())
print(r)  # or do print("Return value: {}".format(r)) to be exact...
```

Output: (`'abcdefghijkl'`)

```
   a
  b l
 c   k
defghij
True
```

Output: (`'abcdefghijklmnop'`)

```
    a
   b p
  c   o
 d     n
efghijklm
True
```

Output: (`'abc'`)

```
False
```

Comment: hi can I ask if this code still works if the output is 'abcd'?

Comment: @JustinLee You can test it (http://www.pyfiddle.io) and scold me for not testing that case ;) - give me a minute

Comment: @JustinLee  fixed it - HTH